# averaging timestamp data giving error in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have been trying very hard to find an answer for a while now. Let me try to iterate the problem.I have a table called myTable: (NOTE:Below table is just a small part of a large table with thousands of rows)

```
timestamp_original            data
2020/05/24 15.30.31.620         0
2020/05/24 15.30.31.649         1
2020/05/24 15.30.31.658         2
2020/05/24 15.30.31.668         3
2020/05/24 15.30.31.688         4
2020/05/24 15.30.31.698         5
2020/05/24 15.30.31.708         6
2020/05/24 15.30.31.738         7
2020/05/24 15.30.31.748         8
2020/05/24 15.30.31.758         9
2020/05/24 15.30.31.768         10
2020/05/24 15.30.31.809         11
2020/05/24 15.30.31.810         12
2020/05/24 15.30.31.812         13
2020/05/24 15.30.31.838         14
2020/05/24 15.30.31.848         15
```

My expectation is to get the average of data between every milliseconds while rounding the millisecond to 10s.

```
timestamp_new                  myData
2020/05/24 15.30.31.6           2.5
2020/05/24 15.30.31.7           8
2020/05/24 15.30.31.8           13
```

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT date_trunc('milliseconds','timestamp_original')::timestamp(1) as timestamp_new, 
avg(data) as myData
FROM myTable
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY timestamp_new;
```

But I am getting the output as follows which does not make any sense

```
timestamp_new                  myData
2020/05/24 15.30.31.6           0.5
2020/05/24 15.30.31.7           5
2020/05/24 15.30.31.8           12
```

Please help me.

Comment: You are missing a group by

Comment: Did you mean to add avg(data) into group by??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion to `timestamp(1)` rounds rather than truncates.  A simple solution is to subtract 50 milliseconds:

```
SELECT date_trunc('millisecond', timestamp_original - interval '50 millisecond')::timestamp(1) as timestamp_new,
       avg(data) as myData
FROM myTable
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY timestamp_new;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=97ccb92075edd2117d8cdaca8cf123e3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: tbh I don't understand the logic for deleting 50 millisecond, but the output is now as desired. If possible could you kindly elaborate. Many thanks for ur support

Comment: @codeheadache . . . I thought I explained that in the question.  The conversion *rounds* the value, so 1.6 goes to 2 (for instance).  You want it to go to 1, so subtract a half.